# “This message has no content” on the new outlook

Tags: email, ms-office, office-365

Every email i send in the new outlook is saved in the “sent” folder but it can’t be opened. It only shows a blank page and “This message has no content” for the preview…

This is a standard IMAP account and i can open the sent email from our webmail just fine, also Apple Mail works fine.

I tried updating outlook and osx ventura to the latest version and deleting and re-adding the account, with no luck.